# May "in with" be used to mean "among?"

Tags: word-usage, prepositions, american-english, british-english

I was thinking about how little I use the word *among* and how I would phrase the dictionary's example sentences for it. Most of it involved substitution with the word *with*. Then I noticed something. For the sentence, "There are peanuts among the almonds," I say, "There are peanuts in with the almonds." However, Dictionary.com, the O.E.D., and Merriam-Webster only list "in with" as meaning "associating with" or "on friendly terms with."

How common is this use of "in with" to mean *among*; would this be understood by a majority of speakers on both sides of the pond; and would this be acceptable under the three Cs (context, convention, and circumstance)?

Comment: What do you think of 'mixed in with' for your nut example? Either way, I wouldn't say that this phrase could step in as a direct substitute for 'among' in all contexts.

Comment: Certainly in the context of the nuts, "in with" works fine (in the US), and probably "sounds better" than "among".  In other contexts it might not work as well, and could even be taken the wrong way.  ("In with" is slang for "colluding with".)

Comment: You certainly could use it that way to get in good with certain audiences, while not my preferred speaking style I have certainly seen the phrase used in just that way.

Comment: @Dodecaphone, yes, I use "mixed in with" too. You're right: It would not be a substitute for "among" in all contexts. I was just referring to this example.

Comment: Do you think people find "among" confusing these days, and believe its use should be minimized?

Comment: @Dodecaphone, I don't think so. Certain uses of "among" sound very natural to me, and I don't remember a time when I didn't understand what it meant. I think the change lies with a few uses that sound too formal (AmE here).

Comment: It depends on your audience, channel and medium. How can we possibly know what will work for you?

Answer (score -1):

As far as I know, *in with* is not a thing: that is, I don't know of such a [compound preposition](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/English_Grammar/Basic_Parts_of_Speech/Prepositions#Compound_Prepositions) or [compound adposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compound_(linguistics)#Compound_adpositions) and the [locution](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/locution#English) is not attested in any dictionary I checked (for instance, in Wiktionary https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/in_with doesn't exist).

If I read a sentence «There are peanuts in with the almonds», my first thought is that a word must have gone missing after "in" due to a typo: «There are peanuts *in the pot* with the almonds».

I wonder if you got confused by some phrasal verb which uses *in* and is followed by *with*, like *go in*: «I go in with my friends». Sure, I'm among friends, but what I said is just that I'm entering some place together with my friends, *in* and *with* just happen to be one after the other.